# Field name already exists

Tags: list, powershell, spfield

All

I have backed up a sharepoint site and restored to another environment. I have a specific list which I want to update the default value of a hidden field in powershell

I found the field, set default value. But when I call field.Update() I see the error below.

I also see this error when I try to create and index on same list. I did quite a lot of search last 2 days, but no luck.

Do you guys have any idea?

> Update : Exception calling "Update" with "1" argument(s): "Field name
>   already e xists. The name used for this field is already used by
>   another field in the list.  Sel ect another name and try again." At
>   line:1 char:14
>   + $field.Update <<<< ($true)
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after more digging, what I found is that, I had 2 different column in that list which has same GUID.

there is a script on [this link](http://blog.sharepoint-voodoo.net/?p=142) which helped me to found those fields.  Then I removed them from my list. Luckily, those fields were not used, so all worked smoothly.

I hope it helps others

Comment: Cool, you can also use SharePoint manager to resolve these issues

Comment: Yes, SP Manager really helped